# Allow spiders to crawl my site (selectable option in wp)

Tags: options, seo

I was creating a site for testing and i selected an option when setting up wp that essentially disallows my site from being indexed/crawled.

I would now like it to be crawled like normal, but i cant find the option within wordpress.

I am running wp 3.5WP

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To allow crawling of your WP site you need to go to "admin panel >> Settings >> Reading" right before the "Save Changes" button is a checkbox with the label **Search Engine Visibility** make sure this is unchecked.

Comment: OMG! ive been ALL OVER this and lmao.........thanks

Comment: After unchecked the box.What option we need to select for front page display.